# Split long annotation string across multiple lines in a docblock

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, annotations

I have a long string in an annotation block, like this one (see `query` property):

```
/**
 * @Table(name="messages")
 * @Entity
 * @NamedNativeQueries({
 *    @NamedNativeQuery(
 *      name = "searchMessages",
 *      resultClass= "__CLASS__",
 *      query = "SELECT * FROM message WHERE id IN (SELECT post_id FROM (SELECT m.post_id, COUNT(*) AS words FROM phpbb_search_wordmatch m INNER JOIN phpbb_search_wordlist w ON w.id = m.word_id WHERE blah blah blah blah ...."
 *    )
 * })
 */
class Message {
...
```

which I would like to split across multiple lines to be more readable.

Is it possible to break the query string in multiple lines?

Comment: The according feature request is https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/issues/91, which is closed because it would cause a backward compatibility break. Instead, there are plans for a new major version which is supposed to have that, see https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/pull/75. Unfortunately, PHP 8 properties rendered this library partially obsolete, so I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for a release.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just found it by myself:

```
/**
 * @Table(name="messages")
 * @Entity
 * @NamedNativeQueries({
 *    @NamedNativeQuery(
 *      name = "searchMessages",
 *      resultClass= "__CLASS__",
 *      query = "SELECT * FROM message WHERE id IN (
          SELECT post_id FROM (
             SELECT m.post_id, COUNT(*) AS words 
             FROM phpbb_search_wordmatch m 
             INNER JOIN phpbb_search_wordlist w ON w.id = m.word_id 
             WHERE blah blah blah blah ...."
 *    )
 * })
 */
class Message {
...
```

This works as expected.

Comment: However, all the spaces, tabs and newlines characteres are part of `query` parameter now. You don't saw any error because they are ignored in SQL queries. For instance, if you do the same with `name` parameter, you will see an error caused by additional spaces.